# Mnesia: how the bag table type is implemented?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a table with an integer key (timestamp) contains the time when particular record should be removed from a database. There is also a cleaning query, which takes from this table records with expiration time less then now and removes them.

Erlang documentation says, that there are four types of table types: `set`, `ordered_set`, `bag`, and `duplicate_bag`.

- `set` is implemented using hash tables, so reading takes O(1) time complexity.
- `ordered_set` is implemented using tree, so reading takes O(log(n)) time complexity, but it better works with consequent intervals.
- I found no information about `bag` implementation.

`ordered_set` seems ideal, but I can't use it because two records can have the same timestamp. So the question is:

How the `bag` table is implemented and is it good with querying consequent intervals? If not, how can I get "`ordered_bag`" functionality?

Comment: I think ordering is very important for time-related applications. Table operations occur only on a specific range in the rows. Without ordering, you must work with the entire table (ok, there are indexes).

So, why not use a tuple key like {Timestamp,ID} where ID is an arbitrary value (in second position in the tuple to preserve timestamp ordering). Why must you have timestamps as the key ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mnesia's `bag` is implemented using `ETS` and `DETS`, so as other table types [1]. Also, Mnesia does not support `duplicate_bag` tables - you can see it from ducumentation [2]. Thus, we can conclude `bag` in Mnesia is implemented as hash table and has constant lookup time, since `ETS` and `DETS` `bag` is implemented as hash table [3]. [4] also says that `set` and `bag` are implemented as hash tables in Mnesia.

1. [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia#whats-mnesia)
2. [Erlang -- mnesia:create_table/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2)
3. [Erlang Programming by Fransecso Cesarini and Simon Thompson, Ch.10](http://www.erlangprogramming.org/)
4. [Erlang and OTP in Action by Martin Logan, Eric Merritt, and Richard Carlsson, Ch.9](http://www.manning.com/logan/)

**On the rest of the question:**

No, `bag` is not good with querying consequent intervals. To get an interval
from `bag` table you must fully traverse it. I see two possible decisions to
that.

**First**, you can use additional `ordered_set` table to keep order, as
@niahoo suggested. Thus, you will be able to efficiently query all timestamps that fall in an interval, and
then delete corresponding entries from your `bag` table, which also will be efficient, since
you will know all keys by this point.

**Second**, you can use `ordered_set` of
`{timestamp, [values]}`. This will require additional manual job on inserting
and deleting single entry, but it will save you from creating additional table
if you only need to query them grouped by `timestamp`.

Comment: why would you use unary tuples instead of the single timestamp ?

Comment: Oh yeah, i mis read your post, i was thinking you were talking about the key field, not the entire record.

Comment: be aware that minimum mnesia tuple size is 3

Comment: @niahoo thank you, you are right (but it's 2, not 3). I guess I just interpolated this from `ETS`. I updated the answer.

Comment: @niahoo I think you are confusing with the minimum number of attributes(which is 2) in an mnesia table with the minimum tuple size.
Since each record in the table would be represented as a tuple of format {table_name, key, attribute_1}, the minimum size of tuple in mnesia is indeed 3.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @TrishaChatterjee , well as I said the minimum tuple size is 3, I think it's zaquest you wanted to reply to.

Comment: Oops! Really sorry...Ya i meant to reply @zaquest
Now I don't have the option to edit

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first think about the most frequent and time critical requests you have to perform with your database to choose the right organization and primary key, I assume (but may be wrong) that it is not the timestamp, nor the cleanup function.

If I am correct, you could simply traverse the table with dirty_first() and then dirty_next() function in order to have perturbations as short as possible (I think that dirty functions are ok since there is no risk that the timestamp is modified . during the operation, and anyway if you don't cleanup an entry you'll do it at next iteration).

Last if time for cleanup is really critical, but timestamp not the most important key for your application, you can store your data in a set using the best key, and in a separate ordered set table the timestamps (primary key) with a list of associated keys.